# How do you get to the new Apple TV's GameCenter logs?

Tags: game-center, tvos, xcode7-beta3

I'm implementing Game Center in our Apple TV app and we're having some issues. I'm hoping that the Game Center logs will help us out. We went to settings and exported the logs, but it says they saved to:

```
file:///var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/GameKit/GameKit-Log%20(name)%20(2015-10-15%20at%2013-54-51%20(MDT)).zip
```

Does anyone know how to access this file?

Answer (score 0):

Sync your device with itunes,
and log data is copied to:
`~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/(device name)/GameKit`